# Historical data for quantitative research and trading?

Tags: market-data, historical-data, intraday

I am interested in global equity 1min/5min/15min/1hour trade-bar data to research micro-market anomalies and trade on them. For that, I need a good historical data vendor, as well as a data vendor that offers live data feeds in order to trade based on the constructed strategies. I found out that Refinitiv has very comprehensive historical global tick data, as well as 1min/5min/15min/1hour trade-bar data. Moreover, Refinitiv seems to have a live data feed as well, which sounds to be a good platform to conduct research and trade based on formed strategies with real-time data. Furthermore, Refinitiv also offers many other data solutions which can be used to further enhance trading strategies (such as corporate actions, analyst forecasts, corporate fundamentals etc.). I am interested if anyone has experience with the Refinitiv data platform used for similar matters, and if someone can elaborate if it is a good data vendor for such a purpose? Additionally, I am interested if someone has any other suggestions for data vendors, such as Algoseek, Tickdata, etc.?

Comment: Refinitiv is probably one of the more expensive but more reliable sources. If you want to get your feet wet with historical data, I have used: https://firstratedata.com/ and it is quite good. They are also in a beta phase of selling tick data as well at this page: https://tickhistory.com/. I have no affiliation with the company.

Answer (score 3):

I work for the Dutch Central Bank and we use Refinitiv for forecasting purposes. Can't comment on the quality of the live feed but the data quality itself is definitely solid.

Answer (score 2):

I bought data recently using [intrinio.com](https://intrinio.com/). Solid quality and not too pricy.